# Young adult 80s novel about second coming of Christ as a horny teenage boy

Tags: identification-request

I read this book in the late 1980s or possibly very early 1990s. It was about the second coming of Christ but extremely blasphemous in its plot line (as far as I recall, Christ had come back as a very horny teenage boy and the second “coming” was a double-entendre).

I am in the U.K. and I think it was by a British author / set in Britain; I also think it may have been by a female author and/or told from the perspective of a female character. I believe it was a young adult novel and was recently published at the time I read it. I think the cover may have had a picture riffing off Michaelangelo’s “Creation of Adam” and it was a “normal sized” paperback novel.

Unfortunately Google results for “second coming” and related phrases are swamped with unrelated results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much, much, much searching I finally found the answer: "Come Again! The Second Greatest Story Ever Told" by Ed Jones.

From the [summary on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/16083679-come-again-the-second-greatest-story-ever-told) it looks like I mis-remembered quite a few key details but I am 100% certain this is the right book because I recognise the cover image (actually a grumpy looking cherub, not the creation of Adam, but close enough that I can see why that tickled the neighbouring neurons in my brain). I've ordered a copy to re-read it.

The Goodreads summary mentions "Theresa, the new Saviour - a shell-suited, down-to-earth teenager." which is the key female character I remembered, although when I said "second coming of Christ as a horny teenage boy" that should in fact have been "horny teenage girl"!

I primarily used [worldcat.org](https://www.worldcat.org/advancedsearch) to search because that let me filter by publication date. I filtered down to books, in English, published between 1985 and 1993 and searched various keywords such as Jesus, Christ, Messiah, coming etc., and waded through the results. At some point during the searching I had a thought that the title might have been a pun about the second coming, and so I did a google search for "phrases containing come" and found that "come again" rang a bell. Back to the WorldCat search for "come again" with the same publication parameters and the result popped out, which I was then able to verify via the Goodreads summary.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation as to what parts of the summary make you believe this is the correct answer? Quotes from it or reviews, for instance. That, and an explanation of how you found the book, will help anyone else who happens to land on this page while looking for a book themselves. Additionally, once two days have passed since the question was posted, please don't forget to accept your own answer to mark the problem as resolved! :)

Comment: @bobble thanks, done! Hopefully my edits are OK.

Comment: These are excellent edits, thank you for sharing. I actually didn't know about WorldCat, that's a nifty tool!